# What is the absolute minimum of $f$ if $f'(x) = (x - 7)(x + 1)(x + 5)$?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Suppose a Calculus course has not taught anything about integrals yet.  How can I tell which of the critical numbers $x=-5$, $x=7$ are lowest given the derivative in the question?

Comment: You don't need integrals to find a fourth degree polynomial whose derivative is $f'(x)$.

Comment: Hmm, tricky. Notice the answer is different for $(x-7)(x-3)(x+5)$, so the middle term must somehow come into the reasoning.

Comment: Is there a reason for excluding $x = -1$ as a possible minimum?

Comment: Good question, @Dan.  I've analyzed the derivative and the function must be increasing right before $-1$ and decreasing right after $-1$, so that is a local maximum.  (Still working on Oscar Lanzi's directions, which seems very new to me.)

Comment: @OscarLanzi With that definition of $g$ it's not true that $g'=f'$

Comment: This is because I missed a sign. Delete.

Comment: Since the derivative is a third order polynomial $x^3+\cdots$,
the slope is negative at large negative $x$, positive at large positive $x$,
so the fourth order polynomial is (apart from factors) $x^4+\cdots$,
enters the region of interest from $\infty$ at negative $x$ and leaves the
region of interest to $\infty$ at positive $x$. As the zeroth of the
slope are at $-5$, $-1$ and $+7$ in that order, they must be a minimum,
a maximum and a minimum from left to right. So the $-1$ is excluded as a minimum.

Comment: It's impossible to know *what* the absolute minimum is. However, one can narrow down **where** it might occur, even without integration. Namely, it must occur at one of the zeroes of the derivative, and specifically, at one where the second derivative is negative. In this case, that would be at $x=-5$ or $x=7.$

Comment: @CameronBuie: I think OP acknowledges this, but wants to know how to decide which one it is, without integration (effectively or otherwise).

Comment: I *think*, with a derivative of the form $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, supposing $a < b < c$, the global minimum is at either $a$ or $c$, whichever is furthest from $b$. Proving this seems fairly straightforward (if it's true, haha), but I'm already staying too late at work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time I am uploading an answer from mobile phone, excited with fingers.

Shifting the polynomial $5$ units to the right we have $$g'(x)=x(x-4)(x-12)=x^3-16x^2+48x.$$
Assuming $g(0)=0$, we need to determine the sign of $g(12)$. It is enough to check the sign of $p(12)$ where
$$p(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{16}{3}x+\frac{48}{2}.$$
Now, $p(12)=-4<0$. Therefore, $x=12$ is the lower local minumum for $g(x)$ and $x=7$ is the lower local minumum for $f(x)$.

Comment: What in the world does $p(x)$ have to do with $g$? Did you mean to look at an antiderivative of $g',$ instead?

Comment: @CameronBuie: It's the antiderivative of $g'$ divided by $x^2$, so it won't change the sign. I get what Bob Dobbs did here, I think, but it could probably use a little clarification.

Comment: Ah, that's what they did. Well, it still rather defeats the purpose of the OP.

Comment: Oh downvoters... The end.